# PDF Livecycle unfillable by pdftk?

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdftk, ubuntu-server

I'm designing a platform to be able to have forms filled out, store the data, and print out pdf's with said data. Simple enough. I can design, save to pdf, and turn that into a pdf form, create the fdf, and pdftk flatten and that all works well and good. However, if I design the pdf form from scratch in LiveCycle designer, the "all's well and good" goes out the window. I've tried messing with the xml, but pdftk doesn't like it.

```
root@UbuServerVMDJenkins:/var/www/carecampus/pdf# pdftk Trial\ 2.pdf fill_form Trial\ 2_data.xml output testagain2.pdf flatten
Unhandled Java Exception:
Unhandled Java Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.NameFinder.lookup(libgcj.so.12)
   at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(libgcj.so.12)
   at java.lang.Throwable.stackTraceString(libgcj.so.12)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.12)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.12)
```

I've tried creating an FDF but it won't fill the form. Any ideas? Tips? Tricks? Preferably, I'd like to be able to go straight from LiveCycle to pdftk. However, I'm flexible, I can code around things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDFTK not working to fill out pdf form created in livecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335279/pdftk-not-working-to-fill-out-pdf-form-created-in-livecycle)

Answer (score 1):

PDF forms created in LiveCycle Designer are not created like any other PDFs. They use an XFA or XML Form Architecture model that your PDFTK library cannot read. See this post: [PDFTK not working to fill out pdf form created in livecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335279/pdftk-not-working-to-fill-out-pdf-form-created-in-livecycle)